# Are Jon Snow and Daenerys Targaryen related?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

Daenerys is a true born Targaryen, but in the last season Jon Snow happened to be the son of Rhaegar Targaryen and Lyanna Stark. So he becomes heir to the throne also. My question is how are these two Targaryen are related?!

Comment: This question has already been answered [on scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133126/how-would-j-and-daenerys-be-related-if-rl-j).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rhaegar was the son of the Mad King Aerys, and older brother to Daenerys and Viserys Targaryen. Lyanna was the only daughter of Rickard Stark, and sister to Ned, Benjen, and Brandon.

Since Jon Snow is the son of Rhaegar and Lyanna, that means **Daenerys is his aunt.**

<sup>[***Source***](http://uk.businessinsider.com/game-of-thrones-jon-snow-and-daenerys-targaryen-related-aunt-nephew-2017-3?r=US&IR=T)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Ah, I wasn't paying enough attention to the Targaryen male names, figured they were brother and sister!  Not sure this is much better, considering what I just saw them do....

Comment: How can Catelyn and Eddard Stark both died in year 299 A.C.? In the series it seems like every season is a year so if Viserys died in 298, Eddard should have died 298/299 and Catelyn/Robb died in 300/301